# How do I add color to my draw_string in MaixPy?

Tags: python, string, image, loops, colors

I am attempting to add color and background color to my img.draw_string text 'Person' in line 4, however to no avail.
I want it to look the same as the lcd text, but it only works with lcd.color. Is there a similar way for the img version?

```
        for i in code:
            a=img.draw_rectangle(i.rect())
            a = lcd.display(img)
            a=img.draw_string(i.x(), i.y()+12, 'Person')
            for i in code:
                lcd.draw_string(i.x(), i.y()+12, 'Person', lcd.RED, lcd.WHITE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found out you had to add color=(r, g, b). Still can't do background color/border color